# MSMQ Transaction with COM (python)?

Tags: python, com, msmq, dynamics-gp, msmq-transaction

I'm attempting to use MSMQ from Python using the win32com library, similar to [this example](http://comsci.liu.edu/~murali/python/python28.txt). I'm able to put messages onto the queue, but in this case it's a transactional queue, so I need to create a transaction around the message send. Basically I'm attempting to do this [VB example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973880.aspx) in python using COM.

I can't figure out how to get the transaction to happen:

```
import win32com.client
transaction=win32com.client.Dispatch("MSMQ.MSMQTransaction")
transaction.Begin()
```

gives:

```
AttributeError: MSMQ.MSMQTransaction.Begin
```

How do I begin the transaction? Am I on the right track?

Comment: For anyone needing the transaction, use `MSMQTransactionDispenser` and its `BeginTransaction` function, which returns an `MSMQTransaction`

Answer (score 4):

You don't need an MSMQtransaction object to send a transactional message to a transactional queue.
Just set the transaction parameter to MQ_SINGLE_MESSAGE when you call Send().

Cheers
John Breakwell

Comment: Thanks John. Now I just have to figure out how to get a hold of the MQ_SINGLE_MESSAGE constant in python/com. You don't happen to know its numerical value by chance? - nevermind, found it: win32com.client.contants.MQ_SINGLE_MESSAGE